# Open GL ES 2.0 Billboard

Tags: view, opengl-es-2.0

I'm trying to create a billboard in OpenGL ES 2.0 . I'm using [this tutorial](http://swiftcoder.wordpress.com/2008/11/25/constructing-a-billboard-matrix/) to create the billboard transformation matrix.

Normally I have the world view projection matrix `wvp` as a uniform in my shader along with the model matrix `m`, and combine with the vertex model coordinate `a_position` to produce the final coordinates:

```
gl_Position = wvp * m * a_position;
```

If billboarding is active for a vertex, and the billboard transformation matrix is called B, then does this mean I should be doing:

```
gl_Position = wv * m * B * a_position;
```

or maybe:

```
gl_Position = wv * m * B;
```

..since the translation component is present in the billboard transformation matrix.

Could someone confirm what is the correct equation for the Billboard version?

Also, is there a way of performing the calculation using `wvp` instead of `wv`, since I prefer to calculate it outside the shader for non-billboard display objects.

Any advice is much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

With opengl es 2 billboards are kinda deprecated.

Simply draw glpoints with a texture uniform in the shader. If i'm not mistaken opengl es 2 treats points by default as pointsprites.
There's an excellent tutorial on this for iphone that applies to android as well. 
I cant think of the url now but I'll get back to you on that.

Edit: Here's the link I was talking about : http://ofps.oreilly.com/titles/9780596804824/ch2d.html#PointSprites